# django admin - how to override add new row in an inlined formset

Tags: django-admin

I've customised my inlined model using the Media class.
I want to customize the inlined field sets to achieve 2 things:

- add a button to each row
- run from javascript code when "add new row" is pressed

I've tried overriding tabular.html and no matter where I put the overriden template, it does not make any difference.

From playing with the change_form.html I can say that I need to override inline_admin_formset.opts.template but I do not know how.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You might get more response if you add some code?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve by adding new button in each row and by the javascript code?

Comment: I have a javascript code that hides some of the fields depending on the selection of other fields. The only problem I have is that it only works when the page is saved and reloaded. What I need to do is to run that javascript when the "add new row" is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. copy
   C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\edit_inline\tabular.html
   to your template folder to use it as a custom template
2. in your admin code, specify the path to the template:

---

```
class PurchaseInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Purchase
    extra = 0
    template = "admin/my_app/shoppingcart/tabular.html"
```

3. modify your custom tabular.html. I just show the bottom part:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function beep(){
  alert('beep');
}

(function($) {
  $("#{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}-group .tabular.inline-related tbody tr").tabularFormset({
    prefix: "{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}",
    adminStaticPrefix: '{% static "admin/" %}',
    addText: "{% blocktrans with inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name|capfirst as verbose_name %}Add another {{ verbose_name }}{% endblocktrans %}",
    deleteText: "{% trans 'Remove' %}"
  });
  $(".add-row a").click(beep);
})(django.jQuery);
</script>
```